# How to remove Message Ui:include not found on java build path in eclipse, While developing .xhtml file using richfaces and facelets?

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml, richfaces, facelets

I am getting error message like...

```
The tag handler class for "ui:include" (null) was not found on the Java Build Path
```

when i placed  or  in my .xhtml file.

What is the reason behind this..

I am using:

```
jsf 1.2
RichFaces 3.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this errors is `jsf-ui.tld` file.

Which define an empty `<tag-class></tag-class>` elements.

Try to remove the .tld from your build path.
This will disable content assistant but surely will remove this annoying error messages.

Answer (score 0):

The tag `<ui:include>` is a components from [Facelets](https://facelets.dev.java.net/) library. In order to use it in your web-application, you must first add the `jsf-facelets.jar` in your application classpath, and then, in each XHTML page that will use some of the `<ui:xxx/>` components, add the `xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"` namespace:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    ...>
    ...
</html>
```